# Mat-autocomplete long string, cursor appears at end of string, how to get cursor at start of string?

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete

I have no idea how to run code snippet for angular app in stackoverflow,

I am using mat-autocomplete ,I have 128 char long name selected, the cursor appends at the end of the string selected instead on the beginning. Have anyone observed this when using mat-autocomplete?

[image]

Here is the example, 
In the stackblitz link [link to code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/romvkygmaaa), I just appended letter 'v' for california, when I select 'california' I see the cursor at end instead I want the cursor at the beginning of the string.

In the code link under app > app.component.ts, check state variable, change name property to 128 char long string then from drop down down select option, you will see cursor appearing at end of string.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug. Autocomplete implements the behaviour of user having typed selection.

Comment: Hi Andrew , thanks for the reply; For my requirement can I override this?

Comment: I have something similiar but this is in javascript, how do I use it in typescript? https://codepen.io/qzzd/pen/RwNWmaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `input` and `textarea` there is no need to create custom **Range** as they provide their own API and in our case `setSelectionRange()` is what we need. But after using that, content of the input is still remains hidden, but looks like `blur()` and `focus()` does the trick.

```
optionSelected(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  input.blur();
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  input.focus();
}

<input ... #input>
<mat-autocomplete ... (optionSelected)="optionSelected(input)">
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngenky?file=src/app/autocomplete-overview-example.html)

Comment: Hi dev, that's perfect solution :), I had been searching across the internet for this solution, how did you find this?

Comment: Hi, experience and imagination :D Can't say its perfect/ Maybe in this simple case is perfect, because solution is very simple. You can inspect the Object in IDE to see what methods it provides and `setSelectionRange` is quite self explanatory. Then check it on MDN.  And for `blur()` and `focus()` - thats the imagination :D Selection can be only one in the DOM, so when you focus, thats where the cursor is placed

Comment: Hi Dev, I added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670262/how-to-display-entire-option-value-when-hovered-in-mat-autocomplete